# How to report log linear models of contingency tables

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, reporting, log-linear

I am using log linear models (`loglm` function, library `MASS` of `R`) to evaluate if 3 variables in a 3 way contingency table are independent.

I build the model of mutual independence

```r
loglm(formula = ~ A + B + C, data = test.t)
```

Which gives me

```r
Statistics:
                      X^2 df P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio 264.7872 50        0
Pearson          292.6937 50        0
```

From what I understand this is the LR test compares my model to the saturated model and observes that there is unexplained variance in my model and significant interactions need to be incorporated, which means I can reject my hypothesis that the 3 variables are independent.

How exactly should I report them this analysis in my report? Do I need to state the LR test values, degrees of freedom and P?

Is this the Pearson Chi square test in the second line? I was under the impression that the Pearson chi square test is only for 2x2 tables (the `chisq.test()` throws an error in bigger tables). Or is it the Pearson chi squared for the 2 models (my model vs the saturated model)?